# Masking the value based on the name using regular expression in JSON string

Tags: c#, regex

The JSON string will be like below

```
{"data": [{

                "id": "BankDetails.FirstName",
                "value": "abcd",
                "type": "Text"

                },
                                {
                "id": "BankDetails.AccountNumber",
                "value": "12345678",
                "type": "Text"
                },
                {
                "id": "BankDetails.SortCode",
                "value": "123",
                "type": "Text"

                }]
                }
```

The "value": "12345678" under the "id": "BankDetails.AccountNumber" should be replaced as "value": "********".  How can we write a Regex Pattern for this?
So the exact output will be

```
{"data": [{

                "id": "BankDetails.FirstName",
                "value": "abcd",
                "type": "Text"

                },
                                {
                "id": "BankDetails.AccountNumber",
                "value": "********",
                "type": "Text"
                },
                {
                "id": "BankDetails.SortCode",
                "value": "123",
                "type": "Text"

                }]
                }
```

*Note*: BankDetails.AccountNumber will not always be the third object.

Comment: Why write a regex, you could simply set the value of the data in the object before serializing to json, assuming you are using that approach.

Comment: Actually this a response from the service, I am logging this.Before logging I am doing the masking.I do not want to add serialization just to mask this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable width positive look behind (supported in C#) to target each digit and replace it with `*` using this regex,

```
(?<="id": "BankDetails.AccountNumber",\s*"value": "\d*)\d
```

**[Regex Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%22id%22%3A%20%22BankDetails.AccountNumber%22%2C%5Cs*%22value%22%3A%20%22%5Cd*%29%5Cd&i=%7B%22data%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%22id%22%3A%20%22BankDetails.FirstName%22%2C%0D%0A%22value%22%3A%20%22abcd%22%2C%0D%0A%22type%22%3A%20%22Text%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%09%09%7B%0D%0A%22id%22%3A%20%22BankDetails.AccountNumber%22%2C%0D%0A%22value%22%3A%20%2212345678%22%2C%0D%0A%22type%22%3A%20%22Text%22%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%22id%22%3A%20%22BankDetails.SortCode%22%2C%0D%0A%22value%22%3A%20%22123%22%2C%0D%0A%22type%22%3A%20%22Text%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D&r=*)**